# Ошибка "NameError: name '' is not defined"

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, обработка-ошибок

Есть 2 класса. Вызываю метод, находящийся во 2м классе, но при его вызове выдает:

> NameError: name 'Vivod' is not defined

Метод вызываю так:

```
 elif self.vib == 2:

                self.v21 = int(input("Введи ID товара на приход: "))
                self.v22 = int(input("Введи прибывшее кол-во товара на склад: "))
                al = self.v21
                lah = self.v22
                vr = Vivod()
                vr.sir(al, lah)
```

второй класс:

```
   from first import *
class Vivod(glav):

# @staticmethod

def sir(self, v22, v21):
    try:
        super().db_conn.execute("""UPDATE product
           SET ostatok=(ostatok+?) WHERE ID=(?)""", (v22, v21))
        super().db_conn.commit()
        super().sklad()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        print("Нельзя сделать приход")
        super().sklad()
    #return print(v22)
```

Answer (score 2):

в файле first в хедере импортируй необходимые либы

```
from second import Vivod
```

dir тебе в помощь

Comment: Пробовал, не работает. Не помог даже прямой путь.:
`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\python\python\second.py')`

Comment: Да что не работает? Полную ошибку кидайте.